# Euler's Continued Fraction Theorem for fractions

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

How can I use [Euler's Continued Fraction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) to find the continued fraction expansion for a (ordinary, finite) fraction via its (terminating or recurring) decimal expansion, rather than via the more obvious Euclid's Algorithm?

The examples I'm thinking of are $5/7$ and $3/8$ each of which can be thought of as a series in a power of $10$:
$$
5/7=0.\overline{571428}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 571428 (10^{-6})^k
$$
and
$$
3/8=0.375=3* 10^{-1}+7* 10^{-2} +5* 10^{-3}.
$$
I'd like to use these coefficients and expansion points together with Euler's Theorem to show the continued fraction expansions
$$
5/7=[0;1,2,2]
$$
and
$$
3/8=[0;2,1,2].
$$

Comment: You say "the" continued fraction. Simple continued fractions (with $1$s in the numerators exclusively) are unique, but not otherwise. That theorem you linked does not seem to be about simple continued fractions, and indeed seems to wind up using rational numbers as the terms if you're basing it off of decimal expansions.

Comment: Okay then, perhaps there will be another step: GCF -> SCF.

Comment: Also, the theorem there is stated for finite sums. Presumably the infinite versions holds too (just take limits of the formula for partial sums), but then that means it would spit out an infinite general continued fraction for e.g. 5/7. I don't see any obvious procedure for converting infinite GCFs to finite SCFs.

Comment: @pdmclean, that 'another step' is very difficult in general case and often amounts to going back to the decimal expansion and using Euclid's algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could use the repeating digits to come up with a non-standard continued fraction in that the terms will not be integers. With sufficient applications of equivalence transforms these can be converted to integers.

in your example:

$$\ a_0 = .571428$$
$$\ a_i = 10^{-6} $$
$$\ x = 5/7 = a_0 + a_0a_1 + a_0a_1a_2+... = \frac {a_0}  {1-\frac{a_1} {1+a_1- \frac{a_2}{1+a_2- \ddots}}} $$
$$\ x = \frac{.571428} {1-\frac{10^{-6}}{1+10^{-6}-\frac{10^{-6}}{1+10^{-6}- 
\ddots }}} $$
$$\ = \frac {571428}{1000000-\frac{1000000}{1000001-\frac{1000000}{1000001-\ddots}}}$$